# How can i dual-boot FreeBSD and PC-BSD -- with GRUB2 in MBR?

Tags: boot, freebsd, grub2, dual-boot, grub

I have a computer with several operating-systems installed on different partitions:

1. FreeBSD
2. PC-BSD
3. Solaris
4. Extended Partition
5. / -partition for Linux-Mint
6. Swap for Linux-Mint
7. /home for Linux-Mint
8. / -partition (and everything) for Linux CentOS

My main OS is Linux-Mint, an Ubuntu derivitive.

I have GRUB2 installed in MBR, and it (GRUB) uses data from the Linux-Mint installation (/boot/grub etc.).

FreeBSD and PC-BSD each has their own 2nd stage boot-loader in their partition.
Solaris has it's own GRUB-installation in it's partition (which act as a 2nd stage boot-loader, enabling me to select between different Solaris-kernels).
Linux-Mint and CentOS are booted by the GRUB in MBR.

+++

My problem is FreeBSD and PC-BSD -- they just won't play nice with eachother!  Even though I've specified different root-partitions etc. in the GRUB-entries for the two BSD-installation; the same one (either FreeBSD or PC-BSD) is booted, no matter if I selected FreeBSD or PC-BSD from the GRUB-menu.

Booting *BSD appears to be a three stage process:  The MBR-loader (1st stage), loads a 2nd stage in the BSD-partitions, which finally loads the actual kernel (3rd stage).

Finally lowering myself to RTFM about booting in *BSD, I discovered the following tidbit about the 2nd stage BSD-bootloader (which has been installed in both of my BSD-partitions):

- If no BSD-partition is marked as the active one (the bootable) in the partition-table, then the loader will commence 3rd stage loading of the BSD-kernel loacated in the *1st BSD-partition* on the disk -- no matter from which BSD-partition the 2nd stage was loaded.  In my case, it'll *always* load FreeBSD (since it's first).
- If on the other hand a BSD-partition is marked as active (bootable), this will be the BSD-kernel that will be loaded as 3rd stage.  In my case, I'll either always get FreeBSD or always get PC-BSD.

Surely there must be some way around this?!  Perhaps somehow skipping the 2nd stage, and let GRUB load the 3rd stage kernel directly -- and then *different* kernels depending on my choice...  Or perhaps some special arguments or configurations for the 2nd stage -- or maybe an alternative 2nd stage loader?  Has someone here come across a similar problem and solved it?

PS: The installation of GRUB in the MBR, overwrote the 1st stage boot-loader installed by FreeBSD (and PC-BSD).  I howver doubt using the FreeBSD 1st stage would've solved my problem, since the problem is (AFAIK) the 2nd stage loader.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would not use MBR, because you have there 4 OS's and that will not go far. You need to have the /boot partition as primary and not extended. So you either throw out the Solaris installation, or the Linux one.
Booting into FreeBSD (or PC-BSD... whatever, makes no difference) with GRUB2 is easy. You just define your "set root=..." and then you say "kfreebsd /boot/loader" and there you go.
For your type, I would use GUID/GPT partition table, there you can also split all partitions up into it, you do not need to have extra BSD slices then.